# Create nested dictionary from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a requirement to create a nested dictionary from a Pandas DataFrame.

Below is an example dataset in CSV format:

```
hostname,nic,vlan,status
server1,eth0,100,enabled
server1,eth2,200,enabled
server2,eth0,100
server2,eth1,100,enabled
server2,eth2,200
server1,eth1,100,disabled
```

Once the CSV is imported as a DataFrame I have:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> 
>>> df
  hostname   nic  vlan    status
0  server1  eth0   100   enabled
1  server1  eth2   200   enabled
2  server2  eth0   100       NaN
3  server2  eth1   100   enabled
4  server2  eth2   200       NaN
5  server1  eth1   100  disabled
```

The output nested dictionary/JSON needs to group by the first two columns (hostname and nic), for example:

```
{
  "hostname": {
    "server1": {
      "nic": {
        "eth0": {
          "vlan": 100,
          "status": "enabled"
        },
        "eth1": {
          "vlan": 100,
          "status": "disabled"
        },
        "eth2": {
          "vlan": 200,
          "status": "enabled"
        }
      }
    },
    "server2": {
      "nic": {
        "eth0": {
          "vlan": 100
        },
        "eth1": {
          "vlan": 100,
          "status": "enabled"
        },
        "eth2": {
          "vlan": 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to account for:

- Missing data, for example not all rows will include 'status'. If this happens we just skip it in the output dictionary
- hostnames in the first column may be listed out of order. For example, rows 0, 1 and 5 must be correctly grouped under server1 in the output dictionary
- Extra columns beyond vlan and status may be added in future. These must be correctly grouped under hostname and nic

I have looked at groupby and multiindex in the Pandas documentation by as a newcomer I have got stuck.

Any help is appreciated on the best method to achieve this.

Comment: pandas has `to_json()` that takes options and may be the desired output.  Maybe the documentation for `to_json()` will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to group the df first : `df_new = df.groupby(["hostname", "nice"], as_index=False)` - note, `as_index=False` preserves the dataframe format.

You can then use `df_new.to_json(orient = 'records', lines=True)` to convert your df to json format (as jtweeder mentions in comments). Once you get desired format and would like to write out, you can do something like:

`with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df_new.to_json(orient='records', lines=True))`